# Is query with JOIN on primary key columns faster than the query without JOIN if both contain WHERE clause for regular non-indexed column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

- Table A: pkA_field;
- Table B: pkB_field, where_field, select_field.

Sample code:

```
SELECT b.select_field
FROM a JOIN b ON a.pkA_field = b.pkB_field // or FROM b
WHERE b.where_field = 'some value'
```

As far as I understand, `JOIN` query is slower as it takes performance to dial with matching rows. So, would it be better to refuse to use `JOIN`? On the other hand, from performance standpoint, `WHERE` filters by non-indexed columns whereas `JOIN` is used on the primary key.

I ran two queries and both gave me 00:00:00 execution time.

Comment: What is your question here? You had a "Question" heading, but you don't actually *ask* anything in that section (and part of the reason why I removed it). What are you asking here? Why is it a problem (?) that both queries ran in < 1 second?

Comment: @ThomA I wonder which one to use. DB is suggested to become bigger every day. Which option would be superior? Is there any sense using JOIN?

Comment: What makes you think join query is slower? Slower than what? An index on where_field would likely make it faster but that index wouldn't be used always. You can experiment with IN and EXISTS as well.

Comment: @AnthonyVoronkov, using JOIN would make sense if it has a purpose (limiting results to those that also exists in A)

Comment: @CetinBasoz What do you mean by saying it won't be used always?

Comment: If you have a trusted foreign key constraint on table b referencing table a, you don't need the join since all rows in table b must exist in table a.

Comment: SQL Server query engine may decide not to use it. There is no guarantee it would be used all the time. Sometines engine may choose to do a table scan instead

Comment: There is no foreign key constraint and I am not the admin of the DB. But, as @CetinBasoz said, I'd better off using JOIN query? In case field used as primary keys imply the same id?

Comment: I didn't say you shouldn't use the JOIN. If JOIN's purpose is to check if those keys are also in A, then it is one way of doing it (or EXISTS, IN query as alternatives). If you didn't have such a purpose then of course the JOIN has no purpose.

Comment: Now it's much clearer

Comment: For questions about performance you need to include the execution plans.

Comment: The _actual execution plan_ is often the place to start analyzing performance issues. Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question. Note that the plan may change as index statistics are updated, SQL Server updates are applied, ... .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no "field" in databases. "field" is a word for farmer to grow potatoes, for the surgeon to operate or in a form to guide user inputs...
In RDBMS we use **column** to designates values in rows in tables.

RDBMS use a branch of mathematics that is the *relational algebra* inside with you will find 8 operators :

**PROJECTION** : retrieving only some colums of the table (that is done in SQL by the SELECT clause of the SELECT command)

**RESTRICTION** : retriening only some rows of the table  (that is done in SQL essentially by the WHERE or HAVING clause of the SELECT command)

**CARTESIAN PRODUCT** : retriening all combination of rows from 1 table to the other (a sort of "multiply" operator whcih is done in SQL with a special JOIN technic... CROSS JOIN)

**DIVISION** : the "reverse" of the cartesian product that is done in SQL by some subqueries depending on some options like valuated division or with or without a rest...

**UNION, INTERSECT, EXCEPT** : which are sets operations

**JOIN** : which consists of comparing certain information from one table with another table

When you do a JOIN, this is not the same as filetring with a WHERE... But some old fashioned syntax simulates a join by a combination of cartesian product and restiction...

Cartesian product can also be done by enumerating all the table in the FROM clause, separates with a comma delimiter...

But this old fashioned syntax lead the RDBMS to correct the query by transforming the "false" join by a real one. In other word, queries writes with :

```
SELECT * FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE table1.ColumnA <compare_to> table2.columnB
```

Are rewrited by the optimizer in :

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON table1.ColumnA <compare_to> table2.columnB
```

Because, in relational algebra, the cost of a cartesian product followeb by a restriction will be extremly heavy...

So the use of index in the most formal syntax or the old fashioned syntax will be strictly the same because of the transformation...

You must understand that a query language like SQL is not a programming language, but a language that you indicate the solution you want to views and not how to do... In other words writing a query is just asking for something and not doing someting...

Cherry on the cake, in some rare cases the old fashioned syntax can exceptionnaly leads to a under optimized solution while JOIN will have the best performances...